# Tkinter buttons not displaying properly

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

This window is intended to display some instructions and present the user with a start button. However, the start button does not display until the frame gets the focus and then it does not display correctly. It shows up as a button with a thin outline, no text, and a background color that matches the frame background. I have tried explicitly setting the background and foreground colors. As best as I can tell, this code should work. I have looked a numerous examples and have not seen a difference.

I am using Python 3.6.2 on a Mac and have added a screenshot of what renders. Any suggestions on how to get the button to render properly would be appreciated.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of what is displayed]

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        instructions = ("Here are some instructions...")
        title = "Title..."

        frame_size_x = 800
        frame_size_y = 600

        self.title(title)
        self.geometry("%dx%d" % (frame_size_x,frame_size_y))

        self.lbl_instructions = tk.Label(self, wraplength=0.90 * frame_size_x, justify='left', text=instructions, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.lbl_instructions.grid(column=1, row=1)

        self.btn_begin = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command = self.start_button)
        self.btn_begin.grid(column=1, row=2)

    def start_button(self, event=None):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my MacBook, running python 3.6.4 on 10.14.1. Do you have any special theming going on? I have the new "dark" theme.

Comment: Try explicitly setting the background and foreground colors like this `self.btn_begin = tk.Button(self, text='Start', bg='grey90', fg='black', command = self.start_button)`

Comment: It works for me using Windows 7 and Python 3.7.1—so it's likely macos-related. Observation: I think naming a method `start_button()` is a little confusing (since it's not a `tk.Button`), and you don't need the `event=None` parameter as it will never be passed an event object argument.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll update my version of python and see if that helps.